# Aestiva HTMLOS debugging

Tags: html, operating-system

I've recently inherited a project with a lot of Aestiva/HTMLOS code. I know this is a pretty old and this probably is a reach, but I'm wondering if anyone could offer advice for debugging this type of code.

For instance, I'd love to have a technique to dump all of the variable set and in scope dynamically, or anything really to help me track and watch Aestivia's call stack and get some meaningful info. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I know htmlos... what do you want to know more specifically? (sorry, in a class atm.. should be able to reply more specifically in a few days. No worries.. htmlos is NOT old! :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Long time HTMLOS programmer here. There is no way to dump all the variables to see which are being used at any given moment.

Here is what you can do. It may or may not be helpful to your situation. HTMLOS uses sessions and by default stores the session information in the URL. So if you look at the URL it will look something like...

```
http://example.com/cgi-bin/htmlos/001052.1.1391600132312275653
```

The first number 00 1052 is the usernum or the session ID.

If you look in your cgi-bin you should find a file called htmlos.conf, and in that it should include a path to the cache folder that htmlos uses. If not specified in there it is usually found in ~cgi-bin/private/cache/

In your cache folder you should find a folder 00 and in it you should find files 1052.a 1052.b 1052.c 1052.opn 1052.v

The 1052.v file contains the cached stuff used in the session. It is proprietery and its format is not known outside of the HTMLOS language developers. You may be ableto get the information you need from look at it.

Any variable declared outside of a function is global.

If you don't like the way HTMLOS handles URLS, you might find my routing library useful... http://clearimageonline.com/route

Answer (score 1):

htmlos is NOT old, in fact, it gets updated every few months or so. :-)
Anyway.. to answer your question.. there is no way to dump all the variables at once.. if you want to know what variables are doing, you can do

```
display variable /display
```

all over the page, so when the page appears you see what the value of the variable is throughout the page. If you don't want to display, you could do this:

```
append variable+LF to file="filename.txt" /append
```

and that would append it to a log file.

If you have any questions.. feel free to ask!